# Want to have a partial update with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form:

```
<% form_tag({:controller => "/faq", :action => 'search_ajax'}, :update => "help_results", remote: true) do %>
```

that is going to the search_ajax action which is supposed to update the help_results div.  That action is supposed to render a partial at the end, but I for sure am having syntax issues:

```
def search_ajax
@categories = HelpCategory.find(:all)

if params[:query].not_blank? && params[:query] != "Search for help about..."
  @query = params[:query]
  @terms = params[:query].split.map {|t| "%#{t.downcase}%" }

  options = {
      :allow_partial_match => true,
      :order => 'fulltext_match_score DESC',
  }
  @results = SearchableText.search_model(HelpItem, @query, options).uniq
  @results = {"Search Results" => @results} if !@results.blank?
  @complicated_query = HelpItem.is_complicated_query?(@query)
  @search_included = true
else
  @results = HelpItem.all.group_by {|item| item.category.name rescue "Misc"}
  @search_included = false
end

render :partial => "results"
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :partial => 'results'
  end
  format.html do
    render :partial => 'results'
  end
end
```

end

Some of the respond_to area is commented out.  I am getting the error message:

```
ActionController::DoubleRenderError in FaqController#search_ajax
```

I know that if I add the `remote => true` helper into my form that the controller action needs to respond to js.  I'm pretty sure this is a syntax error.  The `respond_to` also comes at the end of my controller action.

Comment: Please add the entire contents of the `search_ajax` action. Usually these double render errors have to do with calling multiple `render` or `redirect_to` methods within the same action.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
render :partial => "results"
```

Above the respond_to block

Comment: When I do that the partial is blank and nothing shows.  And when I go submit the form it doesn't look like the ajax is working as it's a new http request.

Comment: You're not passing the results into it.  Try `render :partial => "results", :results => @results`

Comment: still nothing is showing on the initial page load and ajax not working either

Comment: Can you post what's in the partial